# How to avoid repetition within custom java exception classes

Tags: java, exception, inheritance, dry

I like creating `Exception` classes whose names indicate the application-specific problems being noticed and thrown.

To define them, generally a new `class` is defined whose super-class is some `Exception` type.

Due to the multiple common constructors in the parent `Exception` class, generally the sub-class looks something like this:

```
package com.example.exception;

/**
 * MyException is thrown when some application-level expectation is not met.
 */
public class MyException extends Exception {

    public MyException() {
        super();
    }

    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public MyException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

Looking at this from the perspective of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I find this approach tedious, *especially* when `Exception` hierarchies are defined.

I'm familiar with tools like [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) that help with reducing repetition for common Java patterns; are there any suggestions for tools that tackle this specific problem of repetition for exception classes?

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I believe that the point the OP is trying to make is that  if he has 10 custom exception classes, he has to repeat this code in all those exception classes.

Comment: @CKing No, I get it. That would be fine with me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yup. Would be fine with me too. But it's not fine by someone else so it's some food for thought. The only change from one exception class to another is the name of the class.. It's a really good question IMO.

Comment: You can always omit the constructors you're not using.

Comment: @CKing, Thanks for your input; I'm thinking of contributing to Lombok in a way that defines these automatically

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, That's a good point, but then future developers would still have to define them when they needed them; I want to avoid the repetition in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

If you create "business" exceptions, you shouldn't just copy all constructors from `Exception`. Instead, create exceptions that use your business objects. For example, if a request failed which is modeled by your business object `Request` you might create a `RequestFailedException` with a single constructor:

```
public RequestFailedException(Request request) {
    super("Request to " + request.getUrl() + " failed.";
}
```

You could even store a reference to the `Request` object in a field and provide a getter so that the method that handles the exception may get more information about what was happening.

Comment: I agree that for certain `Exception`s, encapsulating relevant information is a good idea, but not all `Exception`s have that requirement; aren't most `Exception`s just custom-named wrappers? I just find it annoying that for those kinds of `Exception`s, all this duplicate code is created.

Comment: I think we (the Java developers) tend to throw exceptions too often. For example, try to offer methods to check some condition beforehand instead of implementing a method, that throws an exception if the condition is not met. Also, if something goes wrong, try to be resilient and return something that may not be perfect but still useful for the caller.

Comment: While I totally agree to what this answer says, it's not what the OP has asked.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner He will avoid repetition, if he follows my suggestion.

Comment: Arguing about usage frequency of and alternatives to exceptions in code is a [straw man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) to the actual problem of defining `Exception` classes succinctly; regardless of usage, subclassing exceptions is a common occurrence in Java. My question is around how those subclasses, when defined appropriately, can be done succinctly.

Comment: @KaushikShankar Okay, I guess mine is not the answer to your question then. Let's wait for someone to provide a more appropriate answer.